# Split long string for each colon ":" and get index of the line by position

Tags: c#

im struggling with the understanding of using Split method to receive my desired texts
im receiving long registration string from user and im trying to split it by colon `:` and for each colon found i want to get all the text until `/n` in the line

The string i'm receiving from the user is formatted like this example:

```
"Username: Jony \n
 Fname: Dep\n
 Address: Los Angeles\n
 Age: 28\n
 Date: 11/01:2001\n"
```

Thats my approche until now didnt figurate out how it works and didnt found question similler like my question

```
str = the long string

List<string> names = str.ToString().Split(':').ToList<string>();
names.Reverse();

var result = names[0].ToString();
var result1 = names[1].ToString();

Console.WriteLine(result.Remove('\n').Replace(" ",string.Empty));
Console.WriteLine(result1.Remove('\n').Replace(" ",string.Empty));
```

Comment: There is no comma

Comment: @Saruman i mean this symbol " : "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex to find the matches after colon and up to the Newline character:

```
(?<=:)\s*[^\n]*
```

The regex uses a look back, ensuring there's a colon in front of the string, then it matches everything not being Newline = rest of line.

Use it like this:

```
string searchText = "Username: Jony\n
 Fname: Dep\n
 Address: Los Angeles\n
 Age: 28\n
 Date: 11/01:2001\n";

Regex myRegex = new Regex("(?<=:)\s*[^\n]*");
foreach (Match match in myRegex.Matches(searchText))
{
    DoSomething(match.Value);
}
```

Comment: the regex works faster then the split process there is some reason for it ?
just ceruis why

btw thanks for the solution ill read more about regex looks like i missed this part i am a begginer

Comment: @tuarek Regex is not faster by any means, though this is a great simple solution

Answer (score 5):

## Benchmarks

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mode             : Release (64Bit)
Test Framework   : .NET Framework 4.7.1 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Operating System : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version          : 10.0.17134
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CPU Name         : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770K CPU @ 3.50GHz
Description      : Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9
Cores (Threads)  : 4 (8)      : Architecture  : x64
Clock Speed      : 3901 MHz   : Bus Speed     : 100 MHz
L2Cache          : 1 MB       : L3Cache       : 8 MB
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Results**

```
--- Random characters -------------------------------------------------
| Value |   Average |   Fastest |   Cycles | Garbage | Test |    Gain |
--- Scale 1 -------------------------------------------- Time 1.152 ---
| split |  4.975 µs |  4.091 µs | 20.486 K | 0.000 B | N/A  | 71.62 % |
| regex | 17.530 µs | 14.029 µs | 65.707 K | 0.000 B | N/A  |  0.00 % |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Original Answer

You could use regex , or you could simply use `Split`

```
var input = "Username: Jony\n Fname: Dep\nAddress: Los Angeles\nAge: 28\nDate: 11/01:2001\n";

var results = input.Split(new []{'\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(x => x.Split(':')[1].Trim());

foreach (var result in results)
   Console.WriteLine(result);
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IckHWq)

**Output**

```
Jony
Dep
Los Angeles
28
11/01
```

**Note** : This has no error checking, so if your string doesn't contain a Colon, it will break

---

**Additional Resources**

[String.Split Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#definition)

> Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance
>   that are delimited by elements of a specified string or Unicode
>   character arr

[StringSplitOptions Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Specifies whether applicable Split method overloads include or omit
>   empty substrings from the return value

[String.Trim Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Returns a new string in which all leading and trailing occurrences of
>   a set of specified characters from the current String object are
>   removed.

[Enumerable.Select Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.